# Comparing communication systems with different modulation orders and code rates

Tags: modulation, qpsk, bpsk, channelcoding, ldpc

I propose an end-to-end communication method in my research. The key part of the method is not the channel coding and modulation but we use them anyway. I am using 1/3 rate Turbo codes with QPSK and benchmark methods use 2/3 rate LDPC codes with BPSK. I want to understand trade-off between modulation order and code rate. For both of the methods, same number of symbols are transmitted for same number of source-encoded bits. Is it an equal comparison? Or changing the code rate has more disadvantages compared to changing modulation order and my system is supposed to have an unfair advantage? I use SNR(dB), not Eb/N0(dB) in x axis.

Comment: Why are you using this combination? It's a bit surprising to use the higher-rate code with the lower-order modulation! Also, why use BPSK at all if your system seems to be phase synchronized enough to generally do QPSK? Since you can project to I and Q orthogonally, you get the "second bit for free", which a professor of mine used to call the "data rate gift of coherent communications", i.e., at the same error rate as BPSK, you get twice as much data across with QPSK.

Comment: Suppose you have 2n source bits. 1/3 rate code maps it to 6n bits and then QPSK maps it to 3n symbols. 2/3 rate+QPSK also generates 3n symbols. I want to use same number of symbols with benchmark method, but for some reason using Turbo codes is better in my case than LDPC, and Turbo codes are by deafult has rate of 1/n when puncturing is not used. I don't use BPSK, the benchmark method uses it. I only wanted to know if "same number of symbols" is a fair comparison method in research.

Comment: But that's not an interesting benchmark! You know the result in advance.

Comment: Well, I do not want to go deep in the details of the project but actually there are much more in the benchmark, channel coding+modulation is only a tool and near-trivial part of it. So we do not know the results beforehand.

Comment: Is this channel highly disruptive on the phase? Because, as said, in additive circularly symmetrically distributed noise, you do.

Comment: No, I work on Rayleigh and AWGN. However, your first comment on "BPSK and QPSK resulting in same BER" does not seem true for every case, clearly in mine when I use 1/3 Turbo codes, BPSK vastly outperforms QPSK.